# Is there any other way than @2x to let iOS know that the graphic is Retina Display ready?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimageview, retina-display

I have a web service producing two versions of graphics; one for Normal Display and another for Retina Display.

Unfortunately I can't add the @2x to the filename since I don't have access to that code.

Is there any way to let the iPhone know that what's loading from the web is a @2x graphic?

Comment: When you download the image you have the opportunity to choose the filename. You can just append "@2x" onto the name of the image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes there is ... when you load an image resource into an UIImage you can set the scale of that image yourself, ie. tell the iOS whether your image is @2x or not.

This is the code to load the @2x images (in the example from a file, but you can put whatever you want):

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]] CGImage] scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

This is the code to load low res images:

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]] CGImage] scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Cheers, Marin